# What is the least restrictive loan in Sweden?

Tags: banking, sweden, financial, loan

My specific situation is I am a Swedish citizen and I currently reside in Sweden, I have very bad credit history, and I am a fulltime student with capital income as opposed to any kind of employment.

(But I consider myself an expat since I moved here and didn’t grow up here.)

Of all the banks and online loans I have explored, the most official banks require good credit history and that you’re employed. Then there is a more flexible tier that is ok with bad credit but requires you to be at least part-time employed. There might be a bottom rung with loans for unemployed people, students, or people seeking work, but I do not if any of those loans will also accept bad credit.

I am curious what the loan is for people at the very bottom who have nothing good to show for themselves except they want a lump sum to try to survive temporarily while they improve their situation like getting a job. Such loans come with the trade-off of high interest.

I currently know of Saldo and Ferratum as possibly loans for unemployed people with bad credit. Is there any loan known to be the most unrestricted, giving almost anyone a loan, even if with high interest?